# PHP insert data failed

Tags: php, mysql

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    try {
        $pdoConnect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:3307;dbname=project","root","usbw");
    } catch (PDOException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
        exit();
    }

    $issue = $_POST['issue'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];

    $pdoQuery = "INSERT INTO `checks`(`issue`, `content`, `contact`) VALUES (:issue,:content,:contact)";

    $pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);

    $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":issue"=>$issue,":content"=>$content,":contact"=>$contact));

    if($pdoExec) {
        echo 'Data Inserted';
    } else {
        echo 'Data Not Inserted';
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="issue" required placeholder="issue"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="content" required placeholder="content"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="contact" required placeholder="contact"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Insert Data">
</form>
```

I failed to insert the record, what is hapeening? I am newbie of coding, can somebody help me?

Comment: and there blows my edit http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42957286/2

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: print out the error message

Comment: Sorry @Fred-ii- , didn't mean to stomp on you :)

Comment: wasn't your fault @dana  OP overwrote my edit with http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42957286/3

Comment: Two resources to see and use http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and apply that to your code. You may also have to remove the port from your connection.

Comment: and whether if you're using this as `http://localhost` (or hosted), or as `file:///` directly in the browser; that part is unknown. If you're not using `file:///`, then check for errors with the links I left you. We/I've done my part; now it's your turn. So, what's the verdict? Or do you still don't know what to do?

Comment: Ok; I've stayed on here trying to help; you've been given comments with no response from you. You've been given an answer now, see that. If you want to ping someone directly, use the @ symbol followed by their member name. I've moved on now, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    try {
        $pdoConnect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project","root","usbw");// take off the port number you provided
    } catch (PDOException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
        exit();
    }

    $issue = $_POST['issue'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];

    $pdoQuery = "INSERT INTO `checks`(`issue`, `content`, `contact`) VALUES (:issue,:content,:contact)";

    $pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);

    $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":issue"=>$issue,":content"=>$content,":contact"=>$contact));

    if($pdoExec) {
        echo 'Data Inserted';
    } else {
        echo 'Data Not Inserted';
    }
}
```

Here is how to connect using pdo 
  `<?php
     $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    ?>`
from php documentation , no port number is provided for localhost ;
 I have testing your code and now it works fine.[image: database entries]
PDO doc is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)
Hope it helps.

Comment: @Tsang Troy, Whenever your question is answered , mark the answer(s)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't keep it simple and less code ?

```
<?php

// error reporting enabled
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

// databse connection
$pdoConnect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project","root","usbw");

if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    $issue = $_POST['issue'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];

    $stmt = $pdoConnect->prepare("INSERT INTO checks ( issue, content, contact ) VALUES (:issue, :content, :contact)");
    $stmt = $pdoConnect->execute(array(":issue"=>$issue, ":content"=>$content, ":contact"=>$contact));

    if($pdoConnect->lastInsertId())
    {
        echo 'Data Inserted';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Data Not Inserted';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: [You already said that...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42957286/php-insert-data-failed#comment73009095_42957286) and OP hasn't commented on that, yet alone all the other comments left.